# Can't post JSON variable with AJAX to PHP

Tags: php, ajax

In the first document I added a JSON string filled with numbers to localstorage like this:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "oyvind_liste.php", 
   data: {aktuelle_verdier: aktuelle_verdier}, 
   dataType: "json",
success: function(result){
   var dataToStore = JSON.stringify(result);
   localStorage.setItem('key', dataToStore);
   }});
```

Then in another document I am trying to post the JSON string retrieved from local storage like this:

```
<script>
var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('key'));
var localData = data.join(", ");

$.ajax({
type: 'post',
       data: {localData: localData}, 
       url: '',
       dataType: "json",
       success: function(result){
       console.log(result)
       }});
</script>
```

The PHP on the same page as the post tries to fetch the data like this:

```
<?php
$user_id = isset($_POST['localData'])?$_POST['localData']:"";
$values = json_decode($user_id);
var_dump($values);
?>
```

When I run var_dump I get `Array()`, so in essence it doesn't post anything. Anyone know whats going wrong?

Comment: Is `data` value being set in your javascript code before you send it to PHP ?

Comment: `localData` isn't JSON, it's just a comma-separated string.

Comment: @Maximus2012 Edited my post, look at the top!

Comment: @Barmar So you're saying I need to encode it before sending it with ajax?

Comment: @ØyvindHjartnes I would say so. Since your PHP code is expecting values in JSON. You might also want to try with `var_dump($_POST)` to see the POST values or even track the request using FireBug plugin.

Comment: @Maximus2012 I did it in the script like this `var json_str = JSON.stringify(localData);`and in the php code like this `$poster = isset($_POST['localData']) ? $_POST['localData'] : array();
$values = json_decode($poster, true);` It gives me an error because it is an array, any ideas?

Comment: Did you try with just `var_dump($_POST)` ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `JSON` when sending an array in an object argument to `$.ajax`. Just put the array there, and jQuery will URL-encode it.

```
var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('key'));

$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    data: { localData: data },
    ...
});
```

Then in PHP you can do:

```
$values = isset($_POST['localData']) ? $_POST['localData'] : array();
var_dump($values);
```

You can also send JSON this way:

```
var json_string = localStorage.getItem('key');
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    data: { localData: json_string},
    ...
});
```

then in PHP do:

```
$values = json_decode(isset($_POST['localData']) ? $_POST['localData'] : '[]');
var_dump($values);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to yield any result, I just get an empty array.

Comment: Thanks for expanding, first `var_dump($values)` reads `array(0) { } `. And `console.log(data)` since I am using `var json_string = localStorage.getItem('key');` so `console.log(json_string)` shows numbers like this `["4", "5", "6"]`

Comment: You're getting that when the page first loads, or when it does the AJAX call? It will probably be less confusing if you used a different script for the AJAX server than the one that displays the page.